# how to import image in scene builder and retain its resolution

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder, gluon

[image]

> I opened a gluon project and started to design a login page. I want to upload an image on an anchor pane as a background of the login page, but the image is blurred and it lost its resolution.
>   What can i do to correct this.

Comment: If you are displaying it at a higher resolution than the image is, you will get pixelation.  Is this happening?  Sometimes if you are displaying it at a different aspect ratio, you can get pixelation and artifacts as well.   Check image dimensions and what you are displaying it in ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you download an image go to properties and under the details check the dimensions if they fit your anchor pane and don’t confuse between pixels and centimeters